# Why doesn't answering or editing community wiki answers raise the question up like normal questions?

Tags: discussion, answers, community-wiki, notifications

I answered a community wiki question for the first time and I didn't see it when I return to the stackoverflow homepage. Why is that? In that case how can people see the new answers in it?

Also, if I get a vote I wasn't notified by stackoverflow like normal too. I don't know if commenting the answer informs me or not but I don't think this is a good feature. Any reason for this?

Comment: Where a question lands on the front page after its edited depends on a number of factors.  It doesn't always land at the top.

Comment: @RobertHarvey which factors are those? I've always seen the new edited post on the front page

Comment: How substantial the edits are, how many there are, other factors.  CW post sometimes became CW because there were so many edits.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Is there no link describing those reasons? (I'd look myself, but I always find it hard to find stuff like that.)

Comment: @trlkly: The actual formula has never been published, AFAIK.